# Laravel 4.2 How to use 2 whereBetween with in OR condition?

Tags: sql, laravel-4, eloquent

What I am expecting is, I need to use 2 whereBetween like this way

```
Model::whereBetween('attr1', [date1, date2])
     ->orWhereBetween('attr2', [date1, date2])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best way, We can simply do what I mentioned in the question :)

```
Model::whereBetween('attr1', [date1, date2])
 ->orWhereBetween('attr2', [date1, date2])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use **advanced wheres**: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#advanced-wheres

So in this case:

```
Model::whereBetween('attr1', [$date1, $date2])
          ->orWhere(function($query) use ($date1, $date2){
               $query->whereBetween('attr2', [$date1, $date2]);
          })
          ->get();
```

If it doesn't work, try to use this alternative.

```
Model::where('attr1', '<', $date1)
       ->where('attr1', '>', $date2)
       ->orWhere(function($query) use ($date1, $date2) {
            $query->where('attr2', '<', $date1)
                  ->where('attr2', '>', $date2);
       })
       ->get();
```

Comment: I was just trying the same.

Comment: Didn't work? I just update my answer, you can try the alternative.